# Netbeans heap size won't increase beyond 1000m?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a large netbeans C++ project and I am getting errors about low memory from the Netbeans IDE. I went in to the netbeans configuration file and modified -J-Xms and -J-XX:PermSize from "32m" to "1000m", which worked. However when I set "2000m" netbeans just wouldnt open. I set it back to 1000m and it worked again (so I was definitely modifying the conf correctly).

I thought this could be because I'm running a 32-bit JVM but when I do java -version I get:

> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.3.1.el6-x86_64 u71-b14)

which I assume means 64-bit? My netbeans config JDK is:

> netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0"

I have a lot of RAM on my machine, how can I allocate more RAM to the netbeans IDE? I need it for speeding-up the code assistance/parsing.

Comment: java -version does not necessarily point to the same JRE as the one configured in the `netbeans.conf` file. What is the `netbeans_jdkhome` property in that file?

Comment: @assylias /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0

Comment: @assylias must be honest I am not sure if this answer means I am using 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: But when you run `java -version`, you are not necessarily addressing the same JVM. Execute `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java -version`.

Comment: It says vOpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)